# XDocument is better than Domain Model

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

In my project, there are multiple xml files. Main xml files contains references of other xml files and so on using Attribute. 
Sample XML 
A.XML

```
<AList>
<A Id="1"><Name>A</Name></A>......
</AList>
```

Id = 1 means read data from B.xml contaijg  Id = 1.

B.xml

```
<BList>
<B Id="1"><Name>A</Name></B>......
</BList>
```

There are around 20 XMl files and these are very complex files. I want to search each and every xml file to find out proper values. 
Approach 1 
Using XDocument, I am loading all these xml and then using XDoucment I am reading values using Descendent property and sending data back to service.

Approach 2 
Write domain model, class containing get and set properties prepared for this. In case of domain model, I have to serialize each and every XML, then using for loop, I have search for right data. Then I have to send this data back to some service.

Which approach is better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your application does is searching data in xml and sending that xml to some service, then there is no need for domain model.

If you have complex business rules, and much more logic, than simply sending xml you have found, then consider to create domain model. In that case you don't need to serialize domain classes into xml to perform search - search will occur on domain entities level (e.g. with some domain service).